# Fraction of non integers?

Tags: arithmetic

By definition of a fraction, can the numerator or the denominator be a non integer ? For example, can we call the expression $\frac{\pi}{2}$ a fraction ?

The popular answer is no, but since the calculus of fractions is valid even with non integers, shouldn't we call $\frac{\pi}{2}$ a fraction after all ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a fraction can have basically any real (or even complex) numbers in the numerator and the denominator. Starting with the real numbers and then allowing fractions does not give you anything *new*, just other ways to write numbers you already have access too (you don't *need* fractions to be able to speak about the real number $\frac\pi2$, it's just very convenient). In contrast with the integers, where allowing fractions gives you a whole bunch of *new* numbers you didn't already have ($\frac12$ is not an integer, for instance).

Note that many people confuse the two concepts (or at least the names) of *fractions* and of *rational numbers*. A rational number is a number which *may be represented*  as a fraction with integers in the numerator and denominator. This doesn't limit fractions to only use integers. It just means that if you have non-integers in your fraction, the number you have is not necessarily a rational number. (And in the case of $\frac\pi2$, that's not a rational number. However, $\frac{\sqrt 8}{\sqrt 2}$ is a rational number, because it may also be written as $\frac21$.)

Comment: rational expression

Answer (score 0):

From [Webster's online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fraction):

> frac·​tion | \ ˈfrak-shən \ 1a : a numerical representation (such as ³/₄, ⁵/₈, or 3.234) indicating the quotient of two numbers

Since $\pi$ (roughly 3.14159) is a number, $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is definitely a fraction by this definition (and I checked that Webster's does consider $\pi$ to be a number).

If we didn't call it a fraction, what would we call it? Though on the other hand, there might not be a practical need to call it anything.

As to whether a given fraction can be rewritten so that both the numerator and denominator are integers, well, I think that's a separate question.